# Mongo Aggregation for Day by group for epoch time

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure from mongo database,(with different epoch time coming from DB),

```
    {
      {
       _id:ObjectId(5e64be116c0a0b7d40e9387a), 
       "macid":"40:A3:6B:70:01:FE"
       "readings":{
          "timestamp":1521438794
          "log":"last log with time"
        }
     },
    {
       _id:ObjectId(5e64be116c0a0b7d40e9387a), 
       "macid":"40:A3:6B:70:01:FE"
       "readings":{
          "timestamp":1584597196
          "log":"last log with time"
        }
    },
    {
       _id:ObjectId(5e64be116c0a0b7d40e9387a), 
       "macid":"40:A3:6B:70:01:FE"
       "readings":{
          "timestamp":1584597607
          "log":"last log with time"
        }
     }
}
```

different epoch time is present in the document.
I want to fetch the data in the following format with local timezone.

```
{
"19 March 2020 ":[
   {
   "log":"last log with time",
   "timestamp" :"11:23:16"},
{
   "log":"last log with time",
   "timestamp" :"11:30:07"},
    ],
"9 March 2018":[{
   "log":"last log with time",
   "timestamp" :"11:23:14"}
    ]
}
```

is it possible via mongo query?.i tried but it's not working and the query is very big to paste here.

Comment: "19 March 2020 ": This is from what field of the input document?

Comment: time stamp in UTC format.it converted to local timezone GMT: Thursday, 19 March 2020 06:00:07
Your time zone: Thursday, 19 March 2020 11:30:07 GMT+05:30

Comment: In MongoDB we cannot format to `19 March 2020 06:00:07` Check [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/). We need to it manually applying a **workaround**

Comment: Valijon ok. can we group without formating